# All of the Signing Identities are Unkown after updating xCode and vs2019

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I have an app on Apple Store I need to update it. Normally I set the project to release-> rebuild ios -> archive ios and distribute. However after upgrading Xcode to 11.4 and Visual Studio 16.5.2. I can not use any signing Identities. All of them are unknown now. How can I fix them any suggestion?
[image]

And also Visual Studio can not detect new Signing Identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug from  Visual Studio 2019 16.5.2. They fixed with 16.5.3
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.5.3

Comment: Ok, then you can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).